# Flutter Just Audio plugin is unable to play complete playlist and gives playback error

Tags: android, flutter, audio-player, just-audio

I am using on_audio_query package to query the list of the audio files.

```
_audioQuery.querySongs(
  sortType: null,
  orderType: OrderType.ASC_OR_SMALLER,
  uriType: UriType.EXTERNAL,
  ignoreCase: true,
)
```

using Just Audio plugin to play the audio files.
Here in the initState function I am preparing a list of AudioiSources from the songModel returned by the query.

```
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  for( int i=0; i<songModel!.length; i++){
    if(i<index){
      uri_list[songModel!.length-index+i] = AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse("${songModel![i].uri}"));
      print("${songModel![i].uri}");
    }
    else{
      uri_list[i-index] = AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(songModel![i].uri!));
      print(songModel![i].uri!);
    }
  }
  _audioPlayer
      .setAudioSource(ConcatenatingAudioSource(children: uri_list))
      .catchError((error) {
    print("An error occured $error");
  });
}
```

** next button works fine, however, only few audio files are running from list and not all.**

```
Widget _nextButton() {
  return IconButton(
    icon: const Icon(Icons.skip_next),
    color: Colors.white,
    onPressed: audioPlayer.hasNext ? audioPlayer.seekToNext : null,
  );
}
```

Here, is the error I am getting.

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(31375): Playback error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(31375):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(31375):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:632)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(31375):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:604)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(31375):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(31375):       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(31375):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(31375):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(31375):   Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.FileDataSource$FileDataSourceException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: : open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

I was expecting that all the audio files will be played from the list.

P.S. I have already checked, that URIs are correct and there is no redundancy in the list.

Comment: What is an example of a URI that works, and what is an example of a URI that fails?

Comment: I think the problem is not with URI. It is just unable to load the last few audio files even if I change the order of URI's in the uri_list. Only the last ones are not being loaded.

Comment: These are the URI's in the list (the output of the print statement in the above code).
I/flutter (10194): content://media/external/audio/media/1000002045
I/flutter (10194): content://media/external/audio/media/1000002537
.
.
.
.
I/flutter (10194): content://media/external/audio/media/4136
I/flutter (10194): content://media/external/audio/media/4137

After seeking to the next URI's a few times, it is unable to load the rest ones ..... irrespective of the URI's. I've tried changing the order ....

Comment: I would suggest submitting a bug report.